# QXmlStreamReader reads empty text, document is for sure not empty

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I'm using `QXmlStreamReader` and `QXmlStreamWriter` to read and write XML files in my application.

My example XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Senders>
    <Sender>
        <Name>COMPANY XYZ</Name>
        <Street>Random</Street>
        <BuildingNumber>23D</BuildingNumber>
        <LocalNumber>123</LocalNumber>
        <CityCode>3434-21</CityCode>
        <City>New York</City>
    </Sender>
</Senders>
```

It was written with my code. Basically, I do not have problem with writing XML files but have some troubles trying to read them after writing. Here's my code, which prints out empty values (XML file is not empty).

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtCore>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QFile file("../data.xml");

    if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QXmlStreamWriter xmlWriter(&file);
        xmlWriter.setAutoFormatting(true);
        xmlWriter.writeStartDocument();

        xmlWriter.writeStartElement("Senders");
        xmlWriter.writeStartElement("Sender");

        xmlWriter.writeTextElement("Name", "COMPANY XYZ");
        xmlWriter.writeTextElement("Street", "Random");
        xmlWriter.writeTextElement("BuildingNumber", "23D");
        xmlWriter.writeTextElement("LocalNumber", "123");
        xmlWriter.writeTextElement("CityCode", "3434-21");
        xmlWriter.writeTextElement("City", "New York");

        xmlWriter.writeEndElement();
        xmlWriter.writeEndElement();

        file.close();
    }

    QVector<QString> data;

    if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QXmlStreamReader xmlReader(&file);

        while (!xmlReader.atEnd() && !xmlReader.hasError())
        {
            xmlReader.readNext();
            if (xmlReader.isStartElement())
            {
                qDebug() << "element name: '" << xmlReader.name().toString() << "'"
                         << ", text: '" << xmlReader.text().toString() << "'" << endl;
            }
        }
        file.close();
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

So what I'm doing wrong while reading my file?

The output I got:

```
element name: ' "Senders" ' , text: ' "" ' 

element name: ' "Sender" ' , text: ' "" ' 

element name: ' "Name" ' , text: ' "" ' 

element name: ' "Street" ' , text: ' "" ' 

element name: ' "BuildingNumber" ' , text: ' "" ' 

element name: ' "LocalNumber" ' , text: ' "" ' 

element name: ' "CityCode" ' , text: ' "" ' 

element name: ' "City" ' , text: ' "" '
```

Comment: Most `XmlReader` APIs I know will output a text when positioned on a text node, but not when positioned on a start element. So if you want to read out content or data then you probably need to add a check for a text node and then output its content.

Comment: See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamreader.html#text which says "Returns the text of Characters, Comment, DTD, or EntityReference.".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are at `StartElement` token, you can only get this element's name, not it's value. You need to read further and get to `Characters` token to be able to read the element's value. You would also want to skip whitespace-only tokens:

```
while (!xmlReader.atEnd() && !xmlReader.hasError())
{
    xmlReader.readNext();
    //here we are at StartElement, so we can read the element's name
    if (xmlReader.isStartElement())
    {
        qDebug() << "element name: '" << xmlReader.name().toString() << "'";
    }
    //here we are inside the element, so if it is not empty, we can read the element's value
    else if(xmlReader.isCharacters() && !xmlReader.isWhitespace())
    {
        qDebug() << "element value: '" <<xmlReader.text().toString() << "'";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and for the example. Now it works.